# How to enable pay with credit/debit card option in paypal live integration using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I am developing ecommerce site using codeigniter framework and working with paypal payment gateway while working with test account when click on checkout button it is redirecting to `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?token=2UB83487A75855947&useraction=commit&rm=2&mfid=1529919438421_bd8c62ee560a7`
 and it will display  pay with debit/credit card options like below

[image]

but same thing when working with live account and sandbox option is set to false

$config['sandbox'] = FALSE; // FALSE for live environment

but while when click on checkout button it is redirecting to

```
https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?token=8XV68932HS353772W&useraction=commit&rm=2&mfid=1529919464344_76e5b0f4b8fe4
```

and it is not displaying pay with credit/debit card options

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Codeigniter issue, it's just that when you're using the sandbox account, it contains all the options which paypal provides but when you're on live the Paypal may not support Pay with debit card to your country.

Second, login to Marchant paypal account and go to setting and make sure that you have enabled to accept credit/debit card.

Comment: for india paypal doesn't provide pay with debit/credit card option